# Can't stop LAMP graceful restart

Tags: apache-2.2, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I just got my first LAMP up and running, everything works fine except that my server is restarting itself every sunday.

When I read the logs I see "Graceful restart requested, doing restart"

Should I just let my server do this or should I stop it?

It seems that some settings get lost in this process, Eg: sudo chown -R name:name /var/logs/

after this restart I dont have the permission and then I have to run

sudo chown -R name:name /var/logs/ 
again in order to get it back.

Here are some logs if it would help:

```
[Sun Sep 15 07:35:02 2013] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2013:07:35:02 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

[Sun Sep 15 07:35:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.17-5+debphp.org~precise+1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Could piped logs help?

I still testing my application so I do have alot of errors.

The "/etc/logrotate.d" says:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your *logrotation* (ex. `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`) there could be a postrotate for your daemon.

Comment: Thanks, this is what it says:

/var/log/apache2/*.log {
 weekly
 missingok
 rotate 52
 compress
 delaycompress
 notifempty
 create 640 root adm
 sharedscripts
 postrotate
  /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
 endscript
 prerotate
  if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
   run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
  fi; \
 endscript
}